# getting papers published when you're not affiliated to a university

Tags: journals

I graduated in Maths 20 years ago, spent a long time away from the subject and recently returned to it. I work entirely alone right now but after a refresher phase, I'm starting to look at some very interesting areas where I can imagine that it would be interesting and not altogether unworthwhile to publish some results later.

The trouble is I no longer have any contacts with a university and the machinery for getting papers refereed and accepted. I've thought about trying to re establish contact with my former University (20 years ago !), have any of you been down this route (successfully) and could give some advice to me on publishing to for example LMS or some other journal ?

Thanks in advance for your advice,
C. Greenhill.

Comment: It is easy to submit papers to many journals online, and not necessary to be affiliated to a University to do so.  Of course, should be reasonably confident that your paper contains new material worthy of publication, and it may not be easy to get independent verification of that if you are unsure yourself and working in isolation.

Comment: Show it to someone in the area first, to be sure that it is not already known, not easy to prove using known techniques, of interest to some audience, likely to be correct, and not missing relevant references.

Comment: Off-topic here, but try this http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/how-do-i-go-about-publishing-a-paper-without-a-university-affiliation

Comment: See also the questions at http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher

Comment: I agree with all of the above comments.  You can submit your paper anywhere regardless of your affiliations.  Probably the most difficult thing for you to know is whether or not your paper will be deemed "on topic".  For that I suggest finding someone close-ish to the field you wish to contribute to and see what the perspective is at present.